# Llamar Activity desde servicio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buen día tengo el siguiente conflicto, tengo dos archivos mi `GeofenceIntentService.java` y mi `BaseActivityHelper.java`

Deseo llamar desde mi `GeofenceInt...` un metodo que tengo en mi `BaseActiv...`

```
GeofenceIntentService.java:


@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(FORZAR_NOTIFICACION, false)) {
            procesarTriggeringGeofences(null);
            mostrarNotificacionDirec();
            dialogDirec();

            return;
        }

        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode()));
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            procesarTriggeringGeofences(triggeringGeofences);
            mostrarNotificacionDirec();
            dialogDirec();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG_LOG, String.format("Código no soportado de transicion de Geofence %s",
                    geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
private void dialogDirec() {
        BaseActivityHelper BAH = new BaseActivityHelper();
        BAH.salirPdvDialog();
    }
```

y:

```
BaseActivityHelper.java:

@ContextSingleton
public class BaseActivityHelper {
    public void salirPdvDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builderr = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity, R.style.StyledDialog);
        builderr.setTitle(R.string.confirmacion_salida_pdv_dir)
                .setMessage(R.string.saliendo_de_punto_dirr)
                .setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog dialog = builderr.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GeofenceIntentService]
    Process: com.android.app, PID: 25724
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: En el código no se muestra donde llamas getSystemService(), agrega esa parte por favor, saludos.

Comment: NO comprendo a que te refieres, es metodo de Context, no?

Comment: Lo sé, pero en el código que agregas en tu pregunta no se ve donde realizas esa parte, desde donde lo llamas?

Answer (score 0):

@Jorgesys Pedona no me deja responder ni editar la pregunta

La llamo en un inicio asi:

```
import android.content.Context;
@Inject
 private Context mContext;
```